# Concise bibliography entry list in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm working on my dissertation right now. I discovered that the structure tab in texstudio lists all the labels defined in a file. I thought it would be nice if I could see a list of labels from the .bib file as well. I wouldn't mind if there was another application that did this. Is this feature implemented anywhere?

Edit: TexStudio sourceforge page has a similar feature request: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/722/

Comment: Have you tried opening a feature request on their sourceforge? http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/

Comment: The labels of the bib files are not displayed as a list anywhere in the GUI. However, the labels are used in the completer.

Comment: I am aware of the keylist feature Tim. However, I use custom reference commands, such as \eref for Equation x.xx and \chref for Chapter y. The keylist doesn't show up for these commands.

Comment: In that case, you should make TXS aware of the meaning of your custom commands using a cwl file. See https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands and the link therein to the cwl description in the manual.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll try that.
It would still be helpful to have a list of citation labels. In a list of 100+ labels, autocompletion gets a bit tricky.

Comment: Your idea is already tracked in an open feature request: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/722/

Comment: Are you asking about labels for cross-references or labels for citations? These are very different things. A reference to an equation or chapter is a cross-reference. A reference to an article you read in Astrophysicists' Weekly is a citation.

Comment: There's always RefTeX ;-)

Comment: Thanks Sean. I haven't heard of RefTex, but I'll give it a try.